# Переход на выделенную строку в datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

На форме есть Datagridview (с bindingsource) с вертикальной прокруткой (более 200 строк), в котором выделена строка и выполнена прокрутка, т.е. выделенная строка скрыта.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как в таком случае (**только когда выделенная строка не видна**), например, при выполнении команды "Удалить строку" (код кнопки ниже) выполнить ее отображение, другими словами, выполнить прокрутку в Datagridview?
Спасибо!

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Удалить эту запись?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        bs.RemoveCurrent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

При выделении строки запоминаете её индекс.

```
int rowIndex = 0;
rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
```

Потом по этому индексу делаете прокрутку.

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = rowIndex;
```